# How to fix SQL Save Error The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I get the following error in C# when I am try to insert data into SQL Server:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The code works fine when I set my system date to `MM/dd/yyyy` but when I change the system settings and change system date to `dd/MM/yyyy` then this error is shown.

I am using SQL Server 2008 with VS-2010

How do I fix it?

Thanks.

**UPDATED :**

I am using this query:

```
INSERT INTO TblName([DATEFILEDNAME] VALUES(N'" + DateTime.Now + "'))
```

Comment: Exactly how you're inserting date ? Share your C# code...

Comment: please put your query here

Comment: I suggest opening sql profiler and looking at the query that is inserting. You will probably notice something unexpected with you date string.

Comment: UPDATE DATEFILEDNAME is DATETIME type in Database

Comment: Simple change the date format to 'MM/dd/yyyy' from c# code while attaching to sql query string.

Comment: @Ray Like DateTime.Now.toString( 'MM/dd/yyyy' ) ???

Comment: yes, that is what i ment :), if you are looking at current date then as mentioned below GetDate() will give you the sql server date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use

```
"INSERT INTO TblName([DATEFILEDNAME] VALUES(GETDATE())"
```

or

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TblName([DATEFILEDNAME] VALUES(@Date)", conn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now
```